# Call from main method, how can I use while or for loop to count when value exceed the given number?

Tags: java

I get the same problem when I try to use sub-module in this question. Could you please help me.

> The problem statement is as follows: 
>    The last passenger should not be counted if his weight, added to the total passengers' weight exceeds the carrying capacity.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Exam2

    {   
        public static void main(String []args)
        {
            int inputmax ;
            int inputweight =0;
            int thesum = 0;
            int count =0;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter maximum of weight: ");
            inputmax = sc.nextInt();
            while(inputmax < 1 )
            {
            System.out.println("Enter positive number of maximum of weight: ");
            inputmax = sc.nextInt();
            }
           while(thesum < inputmax)
           {
               System.out.println("Enter each of weight: ");
               inputweight = sc.nextInt();

               while ( inputweight < 0)
                {
                System.out.println("Enter positive number of weight: ");
                inputweight = sc.nextInt(); 
                }
                thesum += inputweight;
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("Number of people could carry is: " + count(thesum,inputweight,inputmax,count));
        } 
        public static int count(int thesum,int inputweight,int inputmax,int count)
        {
            while(inputweight !=0)
            {
                if(thesum+inputweight >= inputmax)
                {
                    break;
                }    
            }
            return count;
        }
        }
```

Comment: just return `count-1` in your `count(int thesum,int inputweight,int inputmax,int count)`

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change to your while loop in `main`:

```
 thesum += inputweight;
 if(thesum>inputmax)
    break;
 count++;
```

You don't need to have the explicit count function.

Comment: Did you print the count value after this instead of calling the count function?